# Syntax Highlighting with NVelocity in Castle MonoRails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, nvelocity

I'm working with Castle Monorails and NVelocity as a view engine. The syntax highlighting works when I go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension and add "vm" to "HTML Editor" on Editor Experience.

Here's the exception:

When a file does not start with a tag, but with velocity syntax, the syntax highlighting fails. Example

```
#*
Some comment with development notes about this file..
*#
<div>
  <p>The actual markup</p>
</div>
```

Anyone have a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try using [CVSI (Castle Visual Studio Integration)](http://www.jonorossi.com/projects/cvsi/), it's a colorizer and IntelliSense for NVelocity.

Comment: Can also install it via the Extension Manager in VS.NET 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded CSVI for my VS 2013 and nothing worked (neither color coding  nor intellisense) 
I also removed Cached registry values, tried rebooting my system nothing worked. Color coding works in VS 2005 but not on 2010 or 2013. Am I missing anything? 
here is what I did I have downloaded vsix file and ran it it opened a command prompt and did something and nothing happens after that. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

http://jonorossi.com/blog/2014/05/31/castle-visual-studio-integration-0.5.0/

Thanks

Here is what I did 
1. renamed vsix to zip updated extension.vsixmanifest XML file to support .net 2.0 version to 4.5 
2. Built a zip File again with all libraries and manifest file then renamed it back to vsix.
3. Right CLick on .vsix file Open With MS Visual Studio Version selector and then Install.

The above 3 steps did the trick.